# How to find VB.Net WebForms components by ID or part of it?

Tags: vb.net, webforms, components

Need a help guys in knowing how to get a component by ID, I have a loop with some elements named like `TextBox_1`, `TextBox_2`, `TextBox_3`, (...) for example.

I have made a loop based in a data list returned from database. I tried something like

```
Dim count as Integer = 1
Dim TextBox As TextBox = Nothing

    For Each dados In MyListData

       TextBox = CType(Me.FindControl("TextBox_" & count), TextBox)
       TextBox.Text = "My data"

       count = count + 1
    Next
```

The error is triggered in `TextBox.Text = "My data"` showing me that TextBox is an object undefined.. returning `Nothing` in immediate view.

My scenario is a Form using MasterPage which contains the  and englobe it's ContentPlaceholders with some UpdatePanels components. My TextBox are inside the Web Form "Content", which corresponds to the main content ContentPlaceHolder set in the Master.. In the beginning I thought I could find elements with Me.FindControl (as above).. with my fail, I tried with Me.Form, Me.Page and Me.Control but nothing..

The MasterPage is like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
     <!-- My header.. -->
</head>
<body onkeydown="return(event.keyCode!=13);">
    <%--<% If (DesignMode) Then%>
        <script src="Scripts/ASPxScriptIntelliSense.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <% End If%>--%>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" AsyncPostBackTimeout="900">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <div id="buttons">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Header" runat="server">
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
        <div id="container">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Content" runat="server">
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The Form Markup is in this structure:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/MyProject_Master.Master" 
CodeBehind="Page.aspx.vb" Inherits="MyProject.MyForm" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Header" runat="server">
    <!-- Some static HTML -->
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="Content" runat="server">
    <!-- The structure is like: -->
    <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" class="divLargura">
        <tr>
            <td><asp:Label ID="Label_1" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_1" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" Width="97%" Height="18px" ClientIDMode="Static">
                </asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:Label ID="Label_2" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_2" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" Width="97%" Height="18px" ClientIDMode="Static">
                </asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:Label ID="Label_3" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_3" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" Width="97%" Height="18px" ClientIDMode="Static">
                </asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:Label ID="Label_4" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_4" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" Width="97%" Height="18px" ClientIDMode="Static">
                </asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</asp:Content>
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there any relation with ReadOnly?

Answer (score 1):

`Me.FindControl()` is using the `Me` object (the whole form) as the starting point of it's search. That won't work inside of a data-bound control, where you may have a different instance of the control for each record. You have to do your search in the context of a specific row, which is only possible within certain events.

To provide the best fix for this, we'll need to know a little more about your context... where is this code running, how is the TextBox defined in your ASPX markup, and how does `listaEvolucaoAcao` relate to the data that ends up in the control?

---

Still don't have quite enough info, but if it were me I'd have the content area look more like this:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="Content" runat="server">
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" class="divLargura">
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Largura"  ... >
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td><asp:Label ID="rowLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="rowTextBox" runat="server" ReadOnly="true"
             Value='<%# Eval("Item.PropertyName") %>' 
             Width="97%" Height="18px"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</table>
</asp:Content>
```

Then I would set the `MyListData` object as the datasource for the repeater.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Joel! PS: I've changed my data list name to "MyListData" in the example now, think that sounds better. Its's a Web Form using a MasterPage. The MasterPage contains the <form> and englobe it's ContentPlaceholders with some UpdatePanels components. My TextBox are inside the Web Form "Content", which corresponds to the main content ContentPlaceHolder set in the Master.. In the beginning I thought I could find elements with Me.FindControl.. with my fail, I tried with Me.Form, Me.Page and Me.Control. Hope this can clear the scenario. Thanks!

Comment: Great... now edit the question to show all that info. We need the full picture here.

Comment: Thanks @Joel Coehoorn, It's updated now, hope it can help in detail the problem more accurately.

Comment: Still need to know about the method where that original VB.Net code lives.